# How to check String has HTML in freemarker?

Tags: templates, freemarker

I have a problem in freemarker when I'm printing a value. Value can be a simple string with characters like (<,>,&), or html

My value contains data like this

scenario 1.
Major risk factor for Heart disease <40 mg/dl (Males)\nMajor risk factor for Heart disease<50 mg/dl (Female)\nNegative risk factor for Heart disease >60 mg/d

scenario 2.

```html
<ol>\n\t<li>ee<\/li>\n\t<li>5tggdsds#$%@&lt;&gt;&gt;%&amp;*()<\/li>\n<\/ol>\n
```

I'm printing value using this syntax in freemarker

```html
<#escape x as x?html>
       <#noescape>${value}</#noescape>
  </#escape>
```

But I'm getting error for scenario 1

com.openhtmltopdf.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 818; columnNumber: 67; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
2022-05-08 10:23:46

com.openhtmltopdf.exception WARNING:: Unhandled exception. Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 818; columnNumber: 67; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
2022-05-08 10:23:46

ERROR:  'The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.'
2022-05-08 10:23:46

com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
2022-05-08 10:23:46

com.openhtmltopdf.load SEVERE:: Unable to disable XML External Entities, which might put you at risk to XXE attacks
2022-05-08 10:23:46

com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser): org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser

Comment: Why have you included [r] as a tag for this question? Does this question have anything to do with the R language?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know ahead if the string will be plain text or HTML, then in principle it's impossible to solve this, regardless of if you use FreeMarker or something else. So whoever passes this value to you should indicate the format to you as well. If that's not realistic to achieve (for "social" reasons), then perhaps use `value?matches(r".*</?[a-z]+>.*", "ri")` to guess if the value is HTML or not.

Also, if possible, use the non-deprecated form of auto-escaping: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html. It's more terse, but also, with that you can mark values as markup (like in this case, `<#if value?matches(r".*</?[a-z]+>.*", "ri")><#assign value = value?no_esc></#if>`), and after that you can just write `${value}`, etc. Especially handy if you have to pass values to macros, or use them on multiple places otherwise.

Comment: I tried like this, but always else is coming as output

  <#if value?matches(r"/<\/?[a-z][\s\S]*>/i", "ri")>
                                
 <#else>
                                
 </#if>

Comment: @GaneshMandapati Remove the initial `/` and closing `/i`. That's not regular expression syntax. Also `[\s\S]` (means: space, or not space) matches everything, so that must be a mistake.

Comment: can you check this question and help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633642/printing-array-of-objets-in-ftl

Comment: please check above link