# Printing array of objets in ftl

Tags: freemarker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BosEL.png)
My Input Data Array is in the Image attached

```
`<#list blank_3 as data>
    <#if data.template??>
        <#assign test=data.template>
            <#if test["clm-medical-examination"]??>
                Hi
            </#if>
    </#if>
</#list>`
```

I'm getting error in If condition and error message like below
Failed at: #if test["clm-medical-examination"]??
An error has occurred when reading existing sub-variable "clm-medical-examination"; see cause exception! The type of the containing value was: extended_hash+string (org.json.JSONObject wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel)

Comment: @ddekany can you help with error

Comment: Can you show the cause exception, which should be further below in the Java stack trace? (As the error message says "see cause exception!".)

Comment: @ddekany       freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]


Java stack trace (for programmers):

 
 - Failed at: #if test["clm-eye-checkup"]??  [in template "abc1.ftl" at line 968, column 24]
 
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

An error has occurred when reading existing sub-variable "clm-eye-checkup"; see cause exception! The type of the containing value was: extended_hash+string (org.json.JSONObject wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel)
 
FreeMarker template error:

Comment: Still not seeing the cause exception there. You need the full Java stack trace which includes that as well.